# Isotope filtering while maintaining card height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, filtering, jquery-isotope

I am trying to create a layout that can be filtered using [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) or some similar plugin, but I also want to be able to use [Bootstrap's card-decks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-decks) to ensure that each card has the same height.  I would be open to something different if each card and it's sections are the same size.

Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPLqZm

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card-deck p-0" id="isotope">
        <div class="card col-3 p-0 a b">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-3 p-0 a c">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-3 p-0 b c">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-3 p-0 b d">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle or pen ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPLqZm

Comment: don't use card deck, isn't responsive

Comment: you can use `min-height` property for same height, in your pen add css `.card {
  min-height: 50%
}`

Comment: here's an updated one: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPLqZm.  Doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: As soon as you introduce the isotope filtering js you break the grid. Would you consider another filtering tool? Filterizr is good

Comment: I would!  That's why I included in my question "or some similar" plugin

Comment: @brooksrelyt I'm still having the same issue with Filterizr.  It doesn't maintain the height

Comment: Has the JS been properly added? Are you using the most recent versions of code and packages?

Comment: @brooksrelyt yes, everything is working, but the card-deck class does not keep them the same height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this isn't built in but, this can be used as a work around instead of battling two different JS libraries.

Use this custom height equalizer to fix your problem.

Codepen using your example: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/LMvXox

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    equalheight('.card');
});

equalheight = function(container){

    var currentTallest = 0,
    currentRowStart = 0,
    rowDivs = new Array(),
    $el,
    topPosition = 0;
    $(container).each(function() {

        $el = $(this);
        $($el).height('auto')
        topPostion = $el.position().top;

        if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
            for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
        rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
        currentRowStart = topPostion;
        currentTallest = $el.height();
        rowDivs.push($el);
        } else {
            rowDivs.push($el);
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
        }
        for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    equalheight('.card');
});
```

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you!